# Convert String XML fragment to Document Node in Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui, xmlnode

I am trying add a new node to the request via SOAPUI Groovy
I have the String XMl fragment but I am not able to create a node using Groovy for SOAPUI.

For example

```
<entityProps>
  <candidate> <id>1</id><key></key> </candidate>
  <candidate> <id>2</id><key></key> </candidate>
  <candidate> <id>3</id><key></key> </candidate>
  <candidate> <id>4</id><key></key> </candidate>
</entityProps>
```

I want to add new `<candidate></candidate>` nodes to this request.
I already have the string, but I need to convert that into a Document node.

Answer (score 4):

Given the xml that you currently have:

```
String doc = '''<entityProps>
               |  <candidate> <id>1</id><key></key> </candidate>
               |  <candidate> <id>2</id><key></key> </candidate>
               |  <candidate> <id>3</id><key></key> </candidate>
               |  <candidate> <id>4</id><key></key> </candidate>
               |</entityProps>'''.stripMargin()
```

And a fragment String:

```
String frag = '<candidate> <id>5</id><key></key> </candidate>'
```

You can parse the document:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( doc )
```

And the fragment:

```
def fragxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( frag )
```

Then, append the fragment to the root node of the document:

```
xml.appendNode( fragxml )
```

And stream this document back into a String:

```
String newDoc = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield xml }
println newDoc
```

That prints:

```
<entityProps>
  <candidate><id>1</id><key></key></candidate>
  <candidate><id>2</id><key></key></candidate>
  <candidate><id>3</id><key></key></candidate>
  <candidate><id>4</id><key></key></candidate>
  <candidate><id>5</id><key></key></candidate>
</entityProps>
```

(I added the newlines myself to make it easier to read...  the actual String you get is all on one line)